# How to create just one Git repository w/ EGit for multiple existing LibGDX projects in Eclipse w/o revising the existing structure of those projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, libgdx, egit

I'm developing a game using LibGDX, and I used this [LibGDX Project Setup](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2012/04/new-app-libgdx-project-setup/) tool to setup my project. The way it structures the projects in Eclipse is that under the workspace folder, there are multiple projects:

- the common project
- the desktop project
- the android project

The desktop & android projects are the ones that I run to launch the app while the common project is where the main codes are stored and is used by the desktop & android ones.

What I want EGit to do is create a Git repo that contains all three projects. My purpose is so that I can push up that repository to a site (e.g. BitBucket) from one machine, and pull it down from another machine if I need to work on it from somewhere else.

How is this done considering I need all three projects copied exactly as is from one machine to another?

Answer (score 0):

put all three project in one folder and push that project to git

Comment: If I cut-and-paste the three projects into one folder, how would Eclipse resolve than when I launch it again? Would it possibly cause any problems regarding path references or anything? Will I need to close and reload all three projects again in Eclipse? This is why I included "...w/o revising the existing structure of those projects?" in my subject title.

Comment: well thats the only problem.One Better way to do it is u create an entirely new workspace. I too did the same in order to switch to Git

its one time effort but helps a lot